# hello.js Yahoo API Integration

Tags: javascript, html, oauth, yahoo, hello.js

I am trying to do a Yahoo oAuth using `hello.js`. Please find my code that I have written:

```
window.onload = function()
{
hello.init(
{
   // "yahoo" : "M0FZ5t7i"
    "yahoo" : "dj0yJmk9WGJDUHpwMkxBNUxEJmQ9WVdrOU4xcFBZVUo1TldrbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1jMw--"
},
{
  redirect_uri:'staging.name.com',
  oauth_proxy: "https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy"
  //https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/   https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy
});

}
```

and on click of a button I have added:

```
 hello("yahoo").login().then(function()
    {
        // Get Profile
        return hello("yahoo").api('me');
    }).then(function(p)
    {
      console.log(p.name);

    }).then(null, function(e){
        console.error(e);
        alert(e);
    });
```

I am getting invalid credential. Also my question is in `client_id`, what should I use consumer key or Appid?

I have also https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/ to add as a proxy. What field value should go in it? Also what does domain and reference stand for?

Comment: Drew gave you an answer below, was it of any use? It is usual here to upvote and/or accept answers that are useful, so helpers get a little bit of encouragement to carry on helping. Let me know if you would like to know how to do that.

Comment: Downvoted, see above.

Answer (score 2):

- `client_id` should be the consumer_key in OAuth1.
- `domain` should be `staging.name.com` in your case
- `reference` is an arbitary value, i.e. "Local Yahoo"

Your value for `redirect_uri` should be a full URI (i.e. `http://staging.name.com/redirect.html`. Or a relative path.